# mongodb/mongoose - updating using the $ operator loses _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm seeing this weird issue when updating my collection using the '$' operator. Assume the following schema:

```
var mySchema = {
   myArray : [{
       name : String
   }]
};
```

and the following data(the _id attribute gets introduced automatically when pushing to myArray)

```
[{name : 'foo', _id:'1'}, {name: 'bar', _id: '2'}]
```

The following works as expected, it replaces the document without messing with  the _id field:

```
var newFoo = {name : 'newFoo'};

mySchema.findOneAndUpdate({name : 'foo'}, {'$set' : {'myArray.0': newFoo }}},function(error, doc) {
     //the resulting document looks like 
     //{name : 'newFoo', _id : '1'}
});
```

However using the $ operator instead of the array index, will result in losing the _id field:

```
 mySchema.findOneAndUpdate({name : 'foo'}, {'$set' : {'myArray.$': newFoo    }}},function(error, doc) {
     //the resulting document looks like 
     //{name : 'newFoo'}
});
```

Have anyone ever encountered a similar error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an "error" it's by design, and you are doing it wrong for what you really want to be doing as well as what is happening here is not what you think.

In an "update" in MongoDB, any arguments in the "update" portion of the statement are considered to "literally" mean what they are. The [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator exists so that you can specify a "field to update", or more than one, and only have the mentioned fields updated rather than overwrite the whole document.

Even though you specify the array field as a argument here, what is in fact happening is that "whole" array element is being "replaced", and not just the "name" field as is likely your intent.

This listing demonstrates what is happening:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var testSchema = new Schema({
  "list" : [{ "name": String }]
});

var Test = mongoose.model( 'Test', testSchema, "test" );

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

async.series([

  function(callback) {
    Test.remove({},callback);
  },

  function(callback) {
    var test = new Test({ "list": [{ "name": "foo"},{ "name": "bar" }] });
    test.save(function(err,doc) {
      console.log(doc);
      callback();
    });
  },

  function(callback) {
    var newFoo = { "name": "newFoo" };
    Test.findOneAndUpdate(
      { "list.name": "foo" },
      {
        "$set": { "list.0": newFoo }
      },
      function(err,doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        callback();
      }
    )
  },

  function(callback) {
    var newFoo = { "name": "moreFoo" };
    Test.findOneAndUpdate(
      { "list.name": "newFoo" },
      {
        "$set": { "list.$": newFoo }
      },
      function(err,doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        callback();
      }
    );
  }

]);
```

Basically what you are doing. Now look at the output carefully:

```
  _id: 546419d60158d92a6f0167d2,
  list:
   [ { name: 'foo', _id: 546419d60158d92a6f0167d4 },
     { name: 'bar', _id: 546419d60158d92a6f0167d3 } ] }
{ _id: 546419d60158d92a6f0167d2,
  __v: 0,
  list:
   [ { name: 'newFoo', _id: 546419d60158d92a6f0167d5 },
     { name: 'bar', _id: 546419d60158d92a6f0167d3 } ] }
{ _id: 546419d60158d92a6f0167d2,
  __v: 0,
  list:
   [ { name: 'moreFoo' },
     { name: 'bar', _id: 546419d60158d92a6f0167d3 } ] }
```

Here are the results of the three updates, where as you say, the `_id` is indeed missing here after the third statement. But look at the `_id` value in the second statement. It's "different" from the original, so a new "sub-document" has "replaced" the element rather than updating the "name".

There is certainly a bit of "funniness" here, but it is more related to how "mongoose" is translating your statement and not MongoDB. The `_id` values are created by mongoose and not MongoDB here. MongoDB only creates an `_id` value for the "top level" document. Mongoose does this for arrays as it has the default opinion that it's a good thing to have.

So at some point, mongoose "works out" that your "update" will in fact "replace" the element at the specified index and creates a new object as per the schema rules as the argument.

But as stated earlier, this is **not** how [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) was intended to be used. Where you only want to set the "name" property, and no other property of the sub-document, then you specify the "full path" to that property with ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation).

Here is the amended listing that **only** modifies the "name" properties and nothing else:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var testSchema = new Schema({
  "list" : [{ "name": String }]
});

var Test = mongoose.model( 'Test', testSchema, "test" );

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

async.series([

  function(callback) {
    Test.remove({},callback);
  },

  function(callback) {
    var test = new Test({ "list": [{ "name": "foo"},{ "name": "bar" }] });
    test.save(function(err,doc) {
      console.log(doc);
      callback();
    });
  },

  function(callback) {
    var newFoo = { "name": "newFoo" };
    Test.findOneAndUpdate(
      { "list.name": "foo" },
      {
        "$set": { "list.0.name": newFoo.name }
      },
      function(err,doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        callback();
      }
    )
  },

  function(callback) {
    var newFoo = { "name": "moreFoo" };
    Test.findOneAndUpdate(
      { "list.name": "newFoo" },
      {
        "$set": { "list.$.name": newFoo.name }
      },
      function(err,doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        callback();
      }
    );
  }

]);
```

See the two notations in there as `"list.0.name"` and `"list.$.name"` respectively. Now see the difference that makes:

```
{ __v: 0,
  _id: 54641bcfdd89cf2c7299025e,
  list:
   [ { name: 'foo', _id: 54641bcfdd89cf2c72990260 },
     { name: 'bar', _id: 54641bcfdd89cf2c7299025f } ] }
{ _id: 54641bcfdd89cf2c7299025e,
  __v: 0,
  list:
   [ { name: 'newFoo', _id: 54641bcfdd89cf2c72990260 },
     { name: 'bar', _id: 54641bcfdd89cf2c7299025f } ] }
{ _id: 54641bcfdd89cf2c7299025e,
  __v: 0,
  list:
   [ { name: 'moreFoo', _id: 54641bcfdd89cf2c72990260 },
     { name: 'bar', _id: 54641bcfdd89cf2c7299025f } ] }
```

So now you see that in each case the `_id` remains untouched, and this is because "we told the update to leave it alone".

This is basically what you want. When working with the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator to match a found index position mongoose "should not" be assuming that the lack of any arguments further to the right side without ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) means that a new object should be created. Rather you "should" be specifying the whole path to "just the field(s)" that you wish to change.

Comment: Neil, thanks for your detailed explanation. I appreciate it. My question now is, what happens if `myArray` had more than 1 field, and I wanted to update them all? would I have to individually set them? is there a way to do a full array update in one assignment without losing the _id? Thanks